# MS Synch Framework - Synch 2 branches to central branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to create a Synch Module using MS Synch Framework wherein records from 2 branches will be synched into a central branch database. I wanted to achieve this with MS Sql Server 2008 R2. I can't seem to figure out the Synch Framework components I need for this project. Our goal is to be able to synch the records over the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the documentation, there is a walkthrough on how to do it.

see: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx)

don't mind that it says SQL Express, the walkthrough will work with SQL Express, LocalDB, SQL Server and Azure SQL Database as they all use the same SqlSyncProvider.

if the central database is an Azure SQL Database, have a look at these as well: [How to: Configure and Execute Synchronization with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928617.aspx) and [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx)